# Teams Bot: Refresh Tab on Task Submit

Tags: tabs, bots, task, microsoft-teams

I have a Teams Bot with a Home Tab showing information based on user data. I have added AdaptiveCards to Tab where you have a button that shows a Task Dialog. I have search everywhere for a way to update the Home Tab on submission. I also have Buttons that renders a Tab Submission on these I can simple return a list with cards that are updated but with Task Submission I can't find a way.

Anybody have an idea on how I could achieve this?
Have tried printing all context through out the process for some type of replyId or something that could give me a option to rerender.

As a note I have the same implementation in Slack which has a neat feature bot.views.publish where I can update the Home View from where I want. Is there anything similar?

Comment: Could you please check this sample once and let us know if that helps - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-adaptive-cards

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have actually used that exact sample to create that part. The problem is from handleTeamsTaskModuleSubmit there is no connection to the tab it was invoked from. In handleTeamsTabSubmit you can just return a new adaptive card and it gets rendered in the tab. Do you know any way from task submit to refresh the tab or send new adaptive card to it. Have also looked into refresh and action sumbit but have not found any way.

Comment: Currently we can return an adaptive card as mentioned above. It is not possible to refresh the tab on task submit.

Comment: Understand, that sux :(. Thanks for your help thou.